# CSS alternating styling beginning after and reset by a certain element

Tags: html, css

I have a page with an arbitrary number of subsequent `section` elements to which I'd like to give alternating background coloring that is reset by sections having the `role="separator"` attribute:

**HTML code**

```
<main>
    <section></section>
    <section role="separator"></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section role="separator"></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</main>
```

Which basically means that every second (odd) `section` after `section[role="separator"]` should gain a distinct background color. Using the above example, this is what should happen:

1. white
2. white (separator)
3. white
4. gray
5. white (separator)
6. white
7. gray
8. white

This problem can be solved easily using the following CSS (but):

**CSS code**

```
section:not([role="separator"]) + section:not([role="separator"]) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

section:not([role="separator"]) + section:not([role="separator"]) + section:not([role="separator"]) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

...but as you can see, this introduces a severe limiting factor. The fourth subsequent `section:not([role="separator"])` elem's background won't differ from that of the previous one. I could of course just unleash the ***demon*** and put more "immediately followed by" selectors, but you see where that goes.

**What should I use to solve the above problem for any number of subsequent non-separator sections?**

I'd appreciate a CSS-only (CSS3) answer, if that is possible at all.

Comment: AFAIK this is impossible using pure CSS without changing the HTML structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could segregate your DOM there to split the sections out, you could use jquery to style the `:even` elements.

eg.

```
<main>
  <div class="sections">
    <section>1</section>
  </div>
  <section role="separator"></section>
  <div class="sections">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
  </div>
  <section role="separator"></section>
  <div class="sections">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
  </div>
</main>
```

You could use the selector to add an 'odd' class to the correct elements.

```
$('.sections').find('section:odd').addClass('odd')
```

Note, this is zero based so the above adds a class to each element with an even number in.

EDIT:

As sholanozie says, you can just use:

```
.sections section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using jQuery, you could use CSS's [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo-class.